# What kind of architecture to use for non-binary output multi-label image clasification

Tags: classification, image-processing, convolution, multilabel

I want to make a network for making multi-label attribute classifications on images of clothing.

This is a simplified case of what I want to do, I have 9 different attribute categories that I wish to detect on the image of a T-shirt: Color, Arm Type, Collar type, Pattern, Fabric Type, Size, Usage Area, and Style.

However, you may notice that these attributes are non-binary, for example, color attribute of the clothing can take 18 different values or the collar type can take 11 different values like a round collar, bicycle collar, turtleneck, etc.

Most tutorials I could find on the internet are mostly for binary labels like is the picture of a celebrity is bald or not, blonde or not. It is all 1 or 0.

Another important point is that not every attribute has a value for every entry in my dataset. I am planning to train this on a dataset that I custom-made myself and there are different lines of clothing than just t-shirts. For example, in the data labeling files of my dataset, there is not a "collar type" specified for a picture of pants because pants obviously do not even have a collar. So I want to train a multi-label classification model with 9 different outputs with images in a database that has 3-4 attributes labeled each.

I am an engineering student who is just getting in on machine learning and AI so it would be awesome if you can include similar tutorials, articles etc in your answers so I can self-teach myself how to do it.

Thank you so much

Note: I am adding an [excel document](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10yIAuRnnLWPiNEm-chJnfbpDzBIy9Aa5/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=113256240355507725099&rtpof=true&sd=true) that has all the attributes and their possible values for a small sample of my dataset and focuses on *just* t-shirts. I am going to experiment on just t-shirts first then train it on the whole dataset

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question but for NLP. Unfortunately, the internet is packed with a lot of conventional multi-label classifications but nothing for realistic scenarios. I found these links  https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/3465/multi-label-classification-with-non-binary-outputs , https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/32132/multi-label-classification-on-non-binary-labels-with-pytorch, that may come in handy for your case